# Windows USB EFI boot files

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, windows-installation

I've been trying to boot up my Win7 USB stick into EFI mode as the disk I want to install it on, is GPT. I have tried to modify the installation media (including copy `bootmgr.efi`, `bootx64.efi` and such), but I keep getting a `winload.efi file is missing` error, which is a bit weird because setup disks aren't supposed to have a `system32` folder containing a `winload.efi` file.

*My Motherboard certainly supports EFI boot. When inserting my flash drive, I get two options for boot, one bios and one UEFI. Also, I've installed Win8.1 on a GPT disk, as well as a previous win7 install, which I seem to have forgotten how I managed to make it work.*

I've tried going through a lot of topics, and the entire idea about EFI boot using files still remains very foggy in my head.

**So I w would really appreciate it if I get a clear idea of how EFI boot works in this case(more from the perspective of what files are needed):**

1. What are the files needed for EFI boot for a windows setup USB?
2. What files have been renamed but are actually similar files? (such as `bootmfgw.efi` and `bootx64.efi`)

**And the purpose of the other folders/files(correct me if I'm wrong):**

- `sources`: files Windows needs during installation, including the .wim file.
- `boot`: BIOS installation boot files
- `support`: additional tools
- `autorun.inf`, `setup.exe`: Files needed for Autorun

My motherboard also has an option to `Launch EFI shell from file system device`, requiring it to have a `shellx64.efi` file. Is this the same as the `bootmgr.efi` file? Will copying/renaming it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prepare usb stick with rufus and point it to the windows iso, selecting gpt and fat32.  rufus will prepare and populate the efi/ directory on the stick, so you can install windows 7 in efi mode.

Pingers

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail on what Rufus is and why it is a better technique than the one the OP is currently using?

Comment: Ah I had no idea Rufus prepped the WinPE by itself.

Comment: rufus is just one of the many tools to prepare a usb stick for various operations.  It's handy for a windows 7 usb, cos it saves having to prepare the efi folder manually.  The standard iso does not have a complete efi folder.  You can do it manually by simply making a fat 32 partition gpt and copying the windows files out of the iso and onto the stick but it won't boot in efi mode until you prep the efi/ folder manually

Comment: EFI/  
EFI/microsoft  
EFI/microsoft/boot  
EFI/microsoft/boot/fonts  
EFI/microsoft/boot/fonts/cht_boot.ttf  
EFI/microsoft/boot/fonts/jpn_boot.ttf  
EFI/microsoft/boot/fonts/chs_boot.ttf  
EFI/microsoft/boot/fonts/wgl4_boot.ttf  
EFI/microsoft/boot/fonts/kor_boot.ttf  
EFI/microsoft/boot/bcd  
EFI/microsoft/boot/efisys.bin  
EFI/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi  
EFI/microsoft/boot/efisys_noprompt.bin  
EFI/microsoft/boot/cdboot_noprompt.efi  
EFI/boot  
EFI/boot/bootx64.efi

Comment: the bootx64.efi is a renamed clone of c:\Windows\Boot\EFI\bootmgfw.efi which is available from any installed copy of windows

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of tampering with additional ISOs, I've realized that you can just replace the \sources\install.wim file on a Win 8/8.1/10 bootdisk with the one from Win7 to make it work.

1. Just get a Win8/8.1/10 ISO
2. Open it using an ISO-explorer (like UltraISO)
3. Replace \sources\install.wim with that from the Win7 ISO/DVD
4. Save as a new ISO, and/or burn it into the installation DVD or on a USB/external HDD active Fat32 partition.

The installation UI will be of the bootdisk's Win version, but it will certainly install Windows7.

**Conclusion: Perhaps, (my) Windows 7 efi boot files are just... broken.**